# SparseBooleanArray пуст при использовании BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android

Имеется список с чекбоксами. При выборе элементов списка нажимаю на кнопку и хочу выбрать их позиции. Но проблема в том, что объект `SparseBooleanArray` пуст.

```
//Использую BaseAdapter
ParameterPropertyAdapter parameterPropertyAdapter =
        new ParameterPropertyAdapter(this, nn_parameter_propertyList, NN_Order_Profile_id);
//(Контекст, List<ParameterProperties> nn_parameter_propertyList, Id)
//Помещаю адаптер в ListView
lvMain.setAdapter(parameterPropertyAdapter);

fabAddProperty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Берем список не нажатых чекбоксов, но SparseBooleanArray checked пуст 
        SparseBooleanArray checked = lvMain.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) 
        {
            int position = checked.keyAt(i);
            //.....
        }
    }
});
```

Если использую `ArrayAdapter` вместо `BaseAdapter`'a, то могу взять позиции, используя тот же `SparseBooleanArray`:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android.R.id.text1, arrlist);
```

Что я делаю неправильно? Почему `SparseBooleanArray` пустой? Может быть, как-то по-другому можно взять те же позиции?

Comment: Это от того, что  `BaseAdapter` - абстрактный класс и в нем не реализованы многие методы, в частности `getItem()` . Вам нужно переопределить их самостоятельно, чтобы они возвращали требуемый результат.